# Rebooting During Git Bash Rebase Operation

Tags: git, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

If in the middle of a git rebase operation I say git rebase --continue, and I'm then presented with several merge conflicts, will Git Bash let me return to where I left off if I need to reboot my PC now due to a Windows Update? I am using GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

I was scared to reboot and lose what amounted to over a hundred steps of merge conflicts still remaining and having done quite a few of them already. So before I rebooted I got to a safe stopping point by completing the current merge conflicts at this step, running a "git add .", performing a git status. Upon seeing the following message, I then rebooted:

```
all conflicts fixed--run "git rebase --continue"
```

I was then able to recover from where I left off after a reboot.

Upon restarting and returning to a Git Bash session, I just did another git rebase --continue and I was able to move on to the next step. Everything worked seamlessly even after the reboot.